# Help in understanding computer science, programming and abstraction

Tags: programming-languages, c, computer-science, abstraction, sicp

Until now, I always believed that you should learn programming languages that make you do low-level stuff (e.g. C) to understand what's really happening under the hood and how the computer really works. [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61936), [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14744/i-dont-know-c-and-why-should-i-learn-it) and an [answer from this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22525/) reinforced that belief:

> The more I program in the abstracted languages, the more I miss what got me into computers in the first place: poking around the computer and seeing what twitches. Assembler and C are very much suited for poking :)

Eventually, I thought you will become a better programmer knowing this, because you'll know what's happening rather than assuming that everything is magic. And knowing/writing low-level stuff is much more interesting than writing business programs, I think.

But a month ago, I came across this book called [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html). Everything in the web suggests that this is one of the best computer science books, and you will get better as a programmer when reading it.

I'm really enjoying the concepts a lot. But I find that the book makes it seem that abstraction is the best concept in computer science while only spending one chapter on the low-level part.

My goal is to become a better programmer, to understand computer science more and this got me really confused. Mainly shouldn't we avoid all abstractions and observe what really is happening at the very low-level? I know why abstraction is great, but doesn't that prevent you from learning how computers work?

Comment: [Read. Understand.](http://catb.org/esr/writings/unix-koans/ten-thousand.html)

Comment: For any given problem some abstractions will help more and others will get in the way more. For any given problem, you should choose a good tool (with appropriate level of abstraction). Both high level and low level thinking will make you a better programmer. The key is making sure you know when to use an abstraction and when to avoid it (google leaky abstractions).

Comment: Consider this abstraction: your C or asm program sees memory as a huge contiguous array, while the underlying hardware is a very different story. Each person's "low level" is another person's "abstraction".

Comment: You are using abstractions every day. Moreover, many problems are stupidly and unnecessarily hard without(proper) abstractions - but abstracted away are trivial; they just need the right approach. Some fine examples there involve graphs.

Comment: Here is a paradox! You want to avoid abstractions to learn to create them.

Comment: Hummm... Do you really want to understand how the IEEE 754 floating point math standard is implemented, or would you just like to declare floats and doubles, and use abstract math operators like + and *?

Comment: There is too much to computing for you to understand all of the things, all of the time. I write mobile applications, which talk to REST APIs, which talk to SQL databases. If I had to hold in my head all of TCP, HTTP, all 7 layers of the OSI model, the IIS stack, SQL and the architecture of every computer involved, just to write a simple mobile app, I'd have a migraine before lunchtime. Abstractions save you from having to think about the parts that someone else has thought out for you, so that you can think about the new bits that you're adding to the system.

Comment: Can't we have abstraction AND transparency? I.e. use abstraction when it is useful, and use 'low-level' when it is useful. It's not an either-or situation.

Comment: Even if you are correct, then yes, learn the low-level stuff to better understand how it all works. **BUT**, after you do that, you need to go to higher levels so that you can build something that is actually useful and is not excessively expensive or takes too much time to build.

Comment: Also be aware that knowing how computers work, understanding computer science concepts, and being able to work effectively as a professional programmer are three very distinct things.

Comment: The point of abstractions is to make engineering faster and to be able to handle large project with more elegant organization and fewer defects. Once you move beyond writing toy assignments and try to write solutions to real problems, you'll see that you can't always work at a low level and be productive. That may upset you, but that's the job.

Comment: As a general guideline: One should  have a strong grasp of the constructs one level below your current level of abstraction, and some general understanding of those two levels below.  The occasions where any significant benefit will be obtained by a greater understanding are very rare. If digging deeper helps keep you excited about programming then go for it - but on your own time not your employer's.

Comment: Opinion, so a comment instead of an answer: I think there's a connection between the idea, which is popular in academia, that students should learn low-level concepts first, and the fact that about 50% of CS professors have never worked a day in the industry.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: Nice prejudice based on a wrong premise: Most university courses prefer to teach high-level stuff like formal languages, functional programming, logics, and consider low-level stuff such as machine language as something that one should learn in their free time or discuss during lunch breaks.

Comment: @Giorgio If that's true, there must have been a sea change since I tutored university students (15 years ago) and went to university myself (10 years ago).

Comment: the way you explain the difference from duplicate makes this question off-topic ("not about... education advice", see [help/on-topic])

Comment: The problem with SICP is that, while it opens with the eminently sensible remark that computer programs should be written for people to read and understand as a higher priority than for a computer to execute, it then goes on to actually give a book full of example code in Lisp, one of the most ridiculously difficult-to-read languages ever invented.  (Which was set up that way because the science of *parsing*--the formal theory involved in making text understandable to a machine--was in its infancy when Lisp was developed, so they sacrificed readability in favor of ultra-simple parsing.)

Comment: @Mason Wheeler I think I can understand why people find lisp ugly, particularly with nested parens, but for some reason I find it a lot easier to understand. For example I spent three days reading a java implementation of permutating an aray, where as in scheme I got the idea fairly quickly.

Comment: @recursivePointer Was it the same algorithm, or did they just have a really ugly version in Java and a much clearer implementation in the Lisp one?

Comment: @Mason Wheeler that I'm not sure. I saw the java implementation a long time ago. I remembered just copy pasting and running it.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: Maybe it is different from place to place. I finished my study more than 20 years ago and it was mainly theoretical stuff: data structures, operations research, computability, logics, principles of operating systems (not how to use a particular OS). Practical subjects like C and assembly were considered too easy to be worth making a course about: stuff you learn by yourself or discuss with other students over a beer.

Comment: @Giorgio Those are the kinds of things I was referring to as "low-level concepts."  With the exception of knowing how to choose (not write!) appropriate data structures, the concepts you listed are neither necessary nor sufficient for most students' goal of becoming a professional programmer.  A CS degree is a terrible proxy for what employers really need.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: While I agree these concepts are not necessary to learn programming, I believe that they are sufficient. Mastering them will make learning programming a matter of practice. I also know good professional programmers who came from other directions: they have degrees in Mathematics or Physics. They did not directly learn to program during their study but they acquired skills that make learning to program quite easy.

Comment: @recursivePointer
Listen to me and throw in the trashcan all these bogus people. I've programmed low level stuff (RFID readers, barcode scanners) and now I've been thrown in the highest levels of abstraction (asp net mvc 5, unit of work design pattern, MVC and so on).

Here's the truth: Abstractions, frameworks with a lot of abstractions and so on are just toys made by programmers turned into businessman to impress people.

All is procedural, and you can do simple and effective and efficient code without all that *** stuff. Sometimes abstraction does help to break down problems, most times not

Comment: @recursivePointer They invented always higher levels of abstraction to look professional and to be able to be mouthy and look clever in front of clients and people who doesn't know the subject. To other programmers who can do their job they look ridiculous. Most of us, me too, have to bend down to all these abstractions because that's what's required at the workplace, but I've been writing perfectly working, performing and bug free programs without using design patterns, crazy top notch frameworks and all that mainstream stuff, because using cool words and abstractions was the latest fad

Comment: @Liquid Core lets ignore frameworks and design patterns for a bit, and let's disregard the boring business level stuff. I'm interested in the word "abstraction" in terms of how [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) describes it, which, as some answers pointed out, is I think not really the boring and mainstream stuff you speak of :)

Comment: @Liquid Core I hope you can still see this, I'd like to know your opinions of SICP.

Comment: @morbidCode just quote what you want me to read. That book it's confusing and even more bogus than all the cool words programmers turned into marketeers use.

Comment: @Liquid Core nothing in particular, I'm just confused as to how you think the words and terms this book uses is what mainstream people and marketeers use.

Comment: @morbidCode Actually I said that "people" and marketeers use simpler words.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, abstractions don't prevent you from understanding how things work. Abstractions allow you to understand why (to what end) things work the way they do.

First off, let's make one thing clear: pretty much everything you've ever known is at a level of abstraction. Java is an abstraction, C++ is an abstraction, C is an abstraction, x86 is an abstraction, ones and zeroes are an abstraction, digital circuits are an abstraction, integrated circuits are an abstraction, amplifiers are an abstraction, transistors are an abstraction, circuits are an abstraction, semiconductors are an abstraction, atoms are an abstraction, electron bands are an abstraction, electrons are an abstraction (and for all we know it could be abstractions all the way down). By the logic that low level knowledge is required to understand how something really works, if you want to understand how computers really work, you need to study physics, then electrical engineering, then computer engineering, then computer science, and essentially work your way up in terms of abstraction. (I've taken the liberty of not mentioning that [you also need to study math first](https://xkcd.com/435/), to really understand physics.)

Now realistically, the days when you could make sense of computers and programming by building your way up from the lowest level details were the earliest days of computers. By now, this field has advanced too much, to the point where it can't possibly be rediscovered from scratch by a single person. There are hundreds of thousands of very qualified people specializing at every level of abstraction, working hard daily to make advances that you can't hope to understand without spending years of studying a specific portion thoroughly and committing to keeping up with the latest advancements there.

Consider this Java snippet:

```
public void Example() { 
    Object obj = new String("...");
    // ...
}
```

You can easily understand what this snippet promises (and what it doesn't promise), at the level of the Java language. But unless you are well-versed in topics like stack frames, heap data structures, concurrent generational tracing garbage collection, memory compacting, static analysis, escape analysis, virtual machines, dynamic analysis, assembly language and executable space protection, you are wrong if you think that you really know all the low level details that are involved in actually running it on a real computer.

Alternatively, consider this C snippet:

```
void example(int i) {
    int j;
    if(i == 0) {
        j = i * 2;
        printf("Received zero, printing %d", j);
    } else {
        printf("Received non-zero, printing %d", j);
    }
}
```

If you show it to a beginner, they'll tell you that when the argument is non-zero, the residual contents of a memory location will be printed, because "variables are actually just memory addresses behind the scenes" and "when you don't initialize them it simply means that you don't move anything to their address" and "there's nothing magic about them". If you show it to a non-beginner, they'll tell you that this program's behavior is undefined for non-zero values of this function's parameter and the compiler could potentially remove the conditional, treat all arguments to this function as zero, replace all of the function's call spots with calls that pass zero as the argument, set all variables that are ever passed as arguments to this function to zero, or do [other seemingly paradoxical things](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

It's important to realize that you're always working at a level of abstraction. The beginner in this example took everything he/she knows into account and arrived elegantly to a completely wrong answer because (a) he/she didn't read the spec of the language (which is an abstraction *on purpose*, not because C programmers aren't clever enough to understand computer architecture) and (b) tried to reason about implementation details which he/she didn't fully grasp and which have evolved way beyond his/her mental model by now. This example is fictional, but it draws from everyday real-world misconceptions - the kind that sometimes lead to perilous bugs and occasionally famous security holes.

It's also important to see the bigger picture. For example, if you don't understand higher abstractions well enough, you may find out that C has structs, struct pointers of equal sizes, incomplete type declarations and function pointers, and you'll likely see them as a bunch of unrelated features that could occasionally be useful. But if you understand a higher abstraction like OOP well enough, you'll recognize the aforementioned features as the building blocks for OOP concepts: structs can contain other structs (code reuse), data pointers can pass something as a reference (like classes), the fact that these pointers have the same size allows them to be substituted (subtyping), incomplete type declarations allow you to have opaque pointers to structs (private members) and function pointers allow you to build dispatch tables (polymorphism).

In this fictional example, knowledge of an OOP language not only didn't prevent you from understanding C, but it actually taught you concepts that you can carry over to C. These concepts can be applied selectively when you need them to make your code easier to manage even when the language doesn't actively push you towards it. (I would argue that there is a similar relationship between OOP and FP, but let's not get carried away.)

Some of the best programmers I've met are the way they are because they understand abstractions and they can carry their knowledge over to any language, and adapt it to any problem they need to solve, on any level they happen to be working at. Some of the worst programmers I've met are the way they are because they insist on focusing on details and trivia which they don't really understand and which a lot of the time aren't exactly up-to-date, or relevant to the problem, or applicable in the context they attempt to use them in, or have never been true in the first place.

All you need to realize is that there is no single level of abstraction at any given point and a person isn't limited to a single level of abstraction at any given moment. You can understand one, then move on to another. You can employ one, then switch to another - any time you want.

Comment: "they understand abstractions and they can carry their knowledge to any language, and adapt it to any problem they need to solve, at any level they happen to be working on." - I think this is what SICP is hinting at, I just don't understand it well enough. Can you expand on this? Say someday I have mastered abstraction. What advantage would it give me if for some reason I would use a more low-level language (E.G. from scheme to c or whatever) given that c also have abstraction?

Comment: @recursivePointer I've made some edits to expand on that.

Comment: @recursivePointer: The point is that EVERYTHING in programming is an abstraction, at one level or another.  (Yes, even assembly.)  Part of the skill of programming is to know which abstractions to use to best get the desired results.  For instance, some years ago I was given a program written by a CS grad student which used an abstraction - C++ strings - to parse a complicated input file.  It worked, but took about half an hour to do its job.  Switching to a different abstraction (Lex/YACC) got it to run in a few seconds, and shrunk 20K lines of code to 1K.

Answer (score 40):

> Eventually, I thought you will become a better programmer knowing this because you'll know what's happening rather than assuming that everything is magic.

These are not contradictory things. I have no idea how to pave a road, but I know that it is not magic.

> But a month ago, I came across this book called Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs and anything in the web suggests that this is one of the best computer science book and you will get better as a programmer when reading it.

Yes, that is absolutely true.

> Mainly shouldn't we avoid all abstractions and observe what really is happening at the very low-level?

Maybe once or twice, but doing that every time will prevent you from being a good programmer. You don't need to watch the electrons flow through a gate to know that it's not magic. You don't need to see the cpu translate those electrons to the bitwise representation of a number to know it's not magic. You don't need to see those bits go down the wire to know that it's not magic. There are a few dozen abstractions necessary just to put these letters alongside one another. A few hundred probably to get them to your computer from SE's servers.

**Nobody** knows all of them - not in depth.

This is a *very* common problem with beginners in programming. They want to know how things work. They think that low level is the best level, because it gives them the most power, or control, or knowledge. It does not.

Yeah, you can't treat it as magic. But you really don't need to know that stuff either. Concatenating strings by hand isn't interesting. Rolling your own sorting algorithm isn't interesting. Because any programmer can get the same result in a few order of magnitudes less time by using something written by far better programmers decades ago.

Comment: "doing that every time will prevent you from being a good programmer." - this is interesting, but when should we need to actually understand the details? For example, a few years ago while learning java, my professor never mentioned anything about object references. When we say Object foo = new Object() we're just creating an object to memory. It's until I learned a little bit of c++ when I found out java used pointers implicitly. It lead me to understand why my objects are getting their values changed for some unknown reason. So when should we ignore the details and when to focus on them?

Comment: I think the biggest problem beginners have is understanding that there's a difference between "it happens to be that way this time" and "it is guaranteed to be that way", and that they should care. Getting lost in the details looks like a part of that.

Comment: @recursivePointer: No offence but it sounds like you weren't taught Java very well. Those are the absolute basics of the language.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit yes I realized that, and my classmates told me I never have to understand that because references are "abstracted" from the programmer. I'd like to know when to stop digging at the details. I realized references are very important concepts. Should we go deeper than that?

Comment: @recursivePointer: References and pointers are important.  Pointers-to-pointers, maybe not so much.  To keep this in-scope for Java, you should know that there is a garbage collector which reclaims memory you are not using (in C++ you have to delete objects or have a smart pointer do it for you).  You do not need to know the exact algorithm it is using to do that (nor should you rely on said algorithm since Oracle might change it some day).  You might want to know a little about how these algorithms work in theory.  You don't need to see the actual code in practice.

Comment: @recursivePointer I don't think there's necessarily a level you 'should' go to - everything is important to someone. If you want to design web applications, you 'should' probably learn as much as you can about the abstractions that make up a website (Javascript, the DOM, different browsers' implementations of certain features) - if you want to design  kernels, you 'should' probably learn as much as you can about the abstractions that make up a kernel (assembly, memory management, how the *** does a filesystem really work).

Comment: I guess I'm trying to say, find out what you *want* to learn more about, then learn it - you'll be able to apply it somewhere. Don't worry about what you *should* learn more about.

Comment: Ignore abstraction details when you don't know how.  Don't ignore them when you don't know why.  If you know why changing foo's state also changes bar's state it isn't that important how it's implemented unless implementing it is your job.  But if you don't know why that happens you're gonna have problems.  I find I learn the most about whats going on under the covers when things break.  So if you're curious, start breaking things.

Comment: @Kevin, CandiedOrange, Commander Coriander Salamander let's see if I understand what you're really saying with some examples. In java, if we Concatenate two strings, the result is a new string object containing the values of the two strings. If we don't need to, we would not have to know how creating a new string is implemented. But we absolutely have to know that it does creates a new string if you Concatenate strings because strings are immutable. And in c++, when foo1 = foo2 does a copy assignment, it doesn't matter how operator= is implemented, just knowing it copies is enough. That's it?

Comment: @recursivePointer: Yes, I would agree with that.  You should probably know about [C++11 move semantics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics), though, since it means your assignment operator is not always a slow copy.

Comment: @Kevin and another thing, just to make sure I got it right. I indeed don't have to know how java's garbage collector is implemented. But I still have to understand how it works (E.G. it doesn't  always immediately destroy objects by the time there are no more references to it.) Is that correct? Would having a high level understanding of how mark-and-sweep works be unessesary?

Comment: @recursivePointer: You *don't* need to know how mark-and-sweep works at an intimate level.  It would be nice to know that garbage collection usually involves tracing chains of references from one object to the next and seeing which objects are still reachable, but I just told you that, so there really isn't any further research you should need to do unless you want to implement your own garbage collector.  It would also be nice to appreciate the consequences of these facts (e.g. `Object.finalize()` will not be called at any predictable or useful time and is basically worthless).

Comment: @recursivePointer Ultimately, you will need knowledge on both levels. Lower-level knowledge is important when deciding how to implement (and debug!) a particular algorithm; but the choice of the algorithm is likely driven by abstract considerations. For example, some sorting algorithms can be /abstractly/ proven to be worse performing than others, meaning that no amount of lower-lever knowledge will save your day if you start out implementing the wrong algorithm.

Comment: @Lars "algorithms can be /abstractly/ proven to be worse performing than others" - I'm not sure what you mean by "abstractly prove", do you mean big O notation? Or something else?

Comment: @recursivePointer In a way. The Big O-notation is a handy notation to communicate what you find out about an algorithm; the important part is realizing that some algorithms are by nature worse than others doing the same job, and being able to reason about that.

Answer (score 32):

> I know why abstraction is great, but doesn't that prevent you from learning how computers work?

Certainly not. If you want to understand the abstractions at work, then study those abstractions. If you want to understand the low-level technical details of a real, physical, computer then study those details. *If you want to understand both, study both*. (In my opinion, a good programmer will do that.)

You seem to have got yourself stuck in a false dichotomy, as if you can only understand one abstraction level at a time (or, worse, as if only one abstraction level *exists* at a time). That's rather like suggesting that it is fundamentally impossible for someone to have any understanding of both physics and mathematics.

A good start would be discovering the distinction between computer science and programming.

Answer (score 16):

A key skill in programming is simultaneously thinking at *multiple* levels of abstraction.  Another key skill is building abstractions; this skill uses the previous one.  Low-level programming is valuable in part because it exercises and expands both these skills.

SICP models and implements interpreters, simulators for a machine model, and a compiler to that machine model (the output of which can then be run on the simulator).  The machine model, while very simple, is not inherently less low-level than x86_64.  Frankly, a good amount of low-level programming is dealing with arbitrary and arcane hardware/firmware interfaces which are no better than the arbitrary rules of business logic.

Comment: "a good amount of low-level programming is dealing
with arbitrary and arcane hardware/firmware interfaces which are no better than the arbitrary rules of business logic" - can you explain this further? How is that possible?

Comment: Have you ever written a bootloader for x86_64?  If not, try it some time.  Most of the work required is due to backwards compatibility so that programs written in the '70s can still run on your 2016 processor.  Much of the hardware initialization is also tied to interfaces designed in the '80s.  Hardware peripherals are often far worse (in part because there's a lot more of them).  Most of the same pressures exist for both firmware and business software, leading to most of the same problems.

Answer (score 5):

> I know why abstraction is great, but doesn't that prevent you from learning how computers work? Am I missing something?

Go to a magic show and you'll be entertained but you won't understand how the tricks work.  Read a book on magic and you'll learn how tricks work but you still won't be entertaining.

Do both.  Work hard. And you might be both.

I'ved worked at high levels SOLID, bash, UML.  I've worked at low levels, TASM, Arithmetic Logic Units, Analog Circuits.  I can tell you, there is no level at which you can work that there isn't some magic abstracted away from you.

The key certainly is not to understand every level of abstraction at once.  It's to understand one level well enough to use it right and well enough to know when it's time to move to a different one.

> Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.
>
> Arthur C Clark

Answer (score 4):

*What time is it?*

Is it time to become a know-it-all programmer or is it time to become a productive programmer?

Knowing the abstraction layers that exist below those among which you work is a good thing, it grants you a better understanding behind the structure of your work and it will even allow creating better solutions.

Yet, you do that, you study when it is *not* the time to be productive. When it is the time to be productive you take high level tools and build with them. Using all the knowledge you have of how things work, and expressing the solution in terms that makes sense to the problem space.

Of course you would be required to know to use such tools, there is the tradeoff of the time it takes to build with a poor tool [vs](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/06/30/coder-dilemma-6-choosing-the-right-stack/) the time to learn to use a more appropriate tool. That's beyond the scope of this question. Yet, you understand that there is an advantage in knowing diverse tools.

---

> Until now, I always believed that you should learn programming languages that makes you do low-level stuff (e.g. C)

It is not that you *should*, it is that it is a good thing to know low-level stuff.

> to understand what's really happening under the hood and how the computer really works.

First off, you don't need a programing language to have an appreciation of how the computer works. Second... I'm afraid that C may be too high level, and a bit narrow. C is a good mapping of an old version of the hardware architecture, made abstract enough to be source portable to different systems. If you want an in-depth understanding you should aim for assembly language (note that assembly language is an abstraction of machine language).

> Eventually, I thought you will become a better programmer knowing this

Yes, you will become a better programmer by knowing that.

> Because you'll know what's happening rather than assuming that everything is magic.

You don't need to know how things work to know they are not magic. All you need is an appreciation of how they work, what are its costs and what to expect from it.

> And knowing low-level stuff is much more interesting than writing business programs, I think.

Well.... low-level stuff is interesting in the sense that they are thought provoking and inspire curiosity. Business programs may deal with another meaning of interest, one related with money.

Besides, you may be under the impression that all business programs are pretty much the same: some database, some model classes, some CRUD, etc... Those are the boring ones. But look how diverse software is, and how diverse are the business around them. Do not constraint yourself.

> My goal is to become a better programmer, to understand computer science more and this got me really confused.

If you want to become a better programmer, you will learn to write reusable code. Because having code that you can trust to work and you don't have to write again each time will make you more productive (as in: doing the same task in less time, but also as in: having less bugs). If you do this, you may be interested in placing your re-utilizable code in a re-utilizable and sharable format... and maybe even share it with other developers. If at least you even consider doing this, I hope it will develop an appreciation for re-utilizable code shared by others, an appreciation for the usefulness of development tools, and an appreciation for higher level languages. These things make you a better programmer.

On the other hand, if you want to learn computer science you will have to disregard about the specifics. For instance, when it comes to see if an algorithm is more efficient than another, you shouldn't have the results be constraint by the particular CPU you have. Computer science is more akin to math, it is abstract.

> Mainly shouldn't we avoid all abstractions and observe what really is happening at the very low-level?

No, you should not avoid abstractions. And yes, you can observe what happens at fairly low levels.

What time is it? Is it time to learn how stuff works or is it time to be productive?

If it is time to learn how stuff works, then don't avoid the abstractions... observe them in action from the lower level, you even create them yourself! Experience how and why they work the way they do.

If it is time to be productive, then don't avoid the abstractions...
Select the right ones for the task at hand and leverage them.

If you are at all interested in learning how to be more productive, consider that the tools are there to be used. Why would you try to pierce the wood pushing a nail with your bare hands when there are hammers available? [Why would you use a magnetized needle and a steady hand to flip bits in a hard disk when there are text editors at hand?](https://xkcd.com/378/)

*Don't avoid the abstractions, they are tools.*

> I know why abstraction is great, but doesn't that prevent you from learning how computers work? Am I missing something?

You forget that you can learn multiple things. Learning Java doesn't prevent you from learning C, Learning C doesn't prevent you from learning C#. Learning OOP doesn't prevent you from learning data structures, learning data structures doesn’t prevent you from learning AOP. Learning assembly language doesn't prevent you from learning electronics; learning electronics doesn't prevent you from learning logic gates.

---

*Nobody* knows all that there is to make your computer works. But that doesn’t mean that you can reach a comfortable level of knowledge all across. Starting with nuclear physics, and all the way up to user experience, you can find courses online and communities with people willing to help.

Edit: the above one may be an unpopular opinion. I have three things to say about it: 1) I said comfortable - I mean, with yourself. I never said you will be a field expert. 2) I mention online courses as an starting point - and yes, there are online courses on nuclear physics (paid if you want something good, yet online). There are also courses that take you from [logic gates to primitive video games](http://nand2tetris.org/) 3) I understand that there is value in specialziation, and I didn't mean to encourage to learn all.

Yet again, consider if this is the best use of your time... when the client hires you to create a new mobile app, will you halt the project because you are yet to understand how semiconductors work? No, of course you don't.

The why is the detail. You may say "no" becase you are not interested in physics or materials... yet, you should say "no", because it is time to be productive. Regardless we agree that you can choose what abstraction levels you learn.

*You may pretent you have been avoiding abstractions in general, you have only been avoiding some of them.*

---

The approach of understanding everything by dividing it in its components falls short, it has fallen short in many disciplines. That is because there are emergent behaviors that are only visible - and thus can only be studied - when the components are integrated.

Do civil engineers bother by the position of individual atoms? no, they don't. They don't even bother to try to create new materials (that job is for a materials engineer) - for the civil engineer the materials are a convenient abstraction. They don't need to know how atoms are arranged, they need how much they cost and how they behave (how they react to stress, humidly, etc..), and nonetheless they know the materials are not magic.

There is little you can learn about biology if you insist in breaking everything into atoms. There is little you can learn about psychology if you insist in breaking everything into neurons.

You get the idea.

Comment: "all business programs are pretty much the same: some database, some model classes, some CRUD, et" - yeah this is exactly what I think about business software. It's like I'm no longer programming I'm just sticking things together.

Comment: @recursivePointer First off, doing integration is not trivial. With that said, if you are working on information system for internal enterprise use, you will find that kind of software. But there is much more than that, if you want something as broad and yet dissimilar and arguably not boring, consider video games.

Answer (score 3):

Software engineering has multiple levels of detail. Your question is "what is the most rewarding, worthy, interesting level?"

It depends on your task or on what you want to be, what you care about. For big systems you should not care much about bit shifting and clock cycles. For embedded software running on a simple micro controller you will probably want to keep an eye on the ammount of memory you use and you may have to write some primitive timing routines.

Sometimes a choice made on a high abstraction level can impact performance or resource use of your system. Recognizing that and understanding why and how will help making the better choice or finding a way to make an existing system more efficient. This works both ways: knowing there is a high level utility available will keep you from inventing your own wheel in your low level domain. So having some understanding of other levels than the one you are working on may help you be more effective.

On a personal level you may want to ask yourself "do I like laying bricks or do I want to designing houses?" Or maybe make layouts of cities. Or improve the science that makes a stronger, lighter, cheaper brick?

Comment: this is not what is asked. "shouldn't we avoid all abstractions and observe what really is happening at the very low-level? I know why abstraction is great, but doesn't that prevent you from learning how computers work?" See [answer]

Comment: @gnat To you the answer is "no".

Answer (score 3):

The abstractions we teach in computer science are the things which, historically, have been found most beneficial to most people writing most programs.  You can't write a modern program in assembly, just due to the sheer size of modern programs and the time constraints business will place on a developer.  You have to be ready to accomplish your goals without a 100% understanding of what's going on.  The abstractions are powerful tools to help you do just that.

Now in my first sentence, I had a lot of "mosts."  In your career, you *will* find yourself in situations, from time to time, where the abstractions you learned will lead you astray.  At these times, you'll need to dig up other knowledge.  Sometimes, that's as simple as learning the right abstraction for the job.  Other times, it requires exactly what you've done: trying to understand what the underlying system is doing when you use those abstractions.

To take an example, look at multithreading.  Traditional multithreading using mutexes, critical sections, condition variables, etc, is very well understood at an abstract level.  You don't have to understand how the kernel swaps threads in and out, or how the timer driven interrupts steal control away from your user threads to let the kernel do its magic.  You may never need to learn what RCU is, or why at some point deep in the bowels of the kernel, you're obliged to stop using mutexes.  In fact, if you try to understand it from the kernel level, you can make dangerous mistakes.  I can't count the number of race cases I've had to fix because someone thought an operation was "sufficiently atomic" and didn't guard it properly with mutexes.  You have to *really* understand kernels (and compilers) before that knowledge can help you write safe mutlithreaded code.  It's far more effective to do everything at the abstract layer of mutexes.

Now lets push it a little.  Instead of writing "most" mutlithreaded programs, which are just fine with the abstractions, lets start writing the really bleeding edge code, using atomic operations.  Now you can learn atomic operations as an abstract concept, and use them successfully, but you'll be left scratching your head wondering what they were smoking when they put the API together.  There's all sorts of things that show up in the memory synchronization details of atomic operations that make your head hurt.  In this case, learning things from the ground up, like you have mentioned, is very helpful for understanding *why* the abstractions do what they do.  Once you understand what caches do and how they peek and poke eachother to maintain synchronization, you can see why the absurdity of the atomic operation API came about -- it was a hardware necessity.  Once you understand them, you'll be in a better position to understand how to eek those last few milliseconds out of your precious real time algorithm, and save the day!

So both approaches have their value.  You'll be able to produce more valuable code faster if you're willing to accept abstractions without tying them all the way down to hardware.  However, there will be cases where an understanding of the hardware lets you push the boundaries of the abstractions in a way other developers never thought possible.  A happy medium, I say.  Find a balance between both!

Answer (score 2):

On the other end of the spectrum is another book that often gets praised as a classic of how to teach algorithms: Donald E. Knuth’s *Art of Computer Programming*.  DEK gave all his algorithms in a (fake, abstracted) machine language, because in his view, programmers will tend to write code that’s simple and efficient in the language they’re using, and the size and performance of the machine code is what really matters.

That book really is a classic, and he made a great point—mostly.  In order to avoid abstraction that hides the real cost of what the program was doing, his first editions had no operating system and the calling convention of his example programs used self-modifying code.  On a modern desktop processor, programs like that would literally not even run, because the CPU and OS will not allow application code to talk to the hardware directly, and modern CPUs have instruction caches that self-modification would invalidate.

Similarly, if you want to write fast code, you’ll profile and see that the most performance-critical sections are loops that are called frequently.  What’s a loop?  It makes the following guarantees: each iteration will run sequentially, based on arbitrary statements, but usually the value of a loop index that can be modified arbitrarily and has an address in memory that you can retrieve with `&`.  Only, it turns out that, on modern hardware, you get speedups with parallelism: either vectorizing the loop or sharing the work between threads.  And it turns out that the low-level C construct, which mapped very closely to what the PDP machines it was written for originally were capable of doing, breaks a number of guarantees that would be very useful to a modern optimizer.

Some of the programming-language abstractions C doesn’t have, such as `foreach`, containers and iterators, or even functional programming, can compile most of these loops more efficiently and safely today than a lot of the optimizations that once made C code efficient, such as pointer arithmetic and Duff’s Device.  Similarly, DOS games were extremely efficient because they ran so close to the metal, until people only ran them on emulators such as DOSBox.  Nobody worries about code size today, and programmers don’t keep a bunch of counters to time their game because it’s so much simpler now to keep one timestamp and do division and remainder on it.  Much like nobody does multiplication and division by converting to and from tables of logarithms.

One thing you want to understand is how your operations will perform when you implement them **today**.  What runs fast on modern hardware?  But also important is that mathematical elegance is timeless.  You want to be able to express your design clearly and understandably, you want to be able to optimize it efficiently, and you want to be able to understand which parts of the project need refactoring at a lower level of abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in [philipxy's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/308890/73603), anything digital is an abstraction. Even the electrical engineering view of currents and voltages is an abstraction.

I've worked as a computer architect, a compiler writer, and an operating systems developer. I have had the experience of writing Java programs I intended to run on a server I helped design.

Cycle-by-cycle knowledge of exactly how a cache miss would work if the data were going to be modified and was currently in cache in read-only mode in a different processor was far too detailed to be useful when writing a Java program. On the other hand, when I was analyzing the effects on performance of adding a cycle of latency to certain cache miss cases, I needed that level of detail.

A key part of the art of programming is picking the right model for the problem you are solving.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to read [Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Zen-Art-Motorcycle-Maintenance-Inquiry/dp/0099786400/ref=sr_1_1) which addresses this very question. The conclusion that it arrives at is that you should aim to generate the greatest 'Quality' at the level(s) of abstraction that you choose. Sometimes this means understanding more about the levels above and below you, but generally you won't be able to master all levels.

Answer (score 1):

Abstractions are necessary to **manage complexity**, which is the Nemesis of all programmers. It's just as important to learn using abstractions as it is to learn the details behind them.

A solution to a real-world problem needs to have a representation that closely resembles the model of the problem. It's why a dice game has a class called `Die` with a method called `roll()`, and not a block of code with `011100110000001110101000100001010101000100` (assuming those binary digit abstractions made sense on some platform). This has been called the [representational gap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131489062) by Larman. Abstractions allow keeping this gap smaller -- a strategy known as Low Representaitonal Gap (LRG). It makes code easier to trace to requirements and to understand. The [Domain-Driven Design (DDD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) approach is similar.

---

[image: UML class diagram of DiceGame]

As programmers we are naturally attracted to complex puzzles. We are proud when we've solved a complex problem. But the paradox is that we as humans don't get much work done when things are too complex all the time. Keep it simple (via abstractions) is better, if we have a choice.

Comment: @MichaelT Not sure how to comment on this, but I rolled back the edit because the Image is important to stress "real world objects" (LRG) and putting the UML image on IMGUR will lose its source code (the plantuml URL has a key that is a hash of the code to edit the image, as well as the SVG format of the diagram contains text that can be indexed by web crawlers).

Comment: Then link to the source as additional material or put it in a comment. But there have been instances when a site has gone off line, bandwith was limited (and degrading user experience) or images were replaced with malicious content in the past. Images should be hosted on stack.imgur to make sure that there is proper accessibility and permanence of the material in the question.

Comment: As an aside, look to see if you can export them in a different format that embeds the material in the image.  If you look at the images in [this post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/287263/40980) and use http://www.draw.io you can import the image back in directly ([example](https://www.draw.io/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FwNAIk.png)).  Note that the image is still hosted on stack.imgur.

Comment: @MichaelT I like that example. I think PlantUML has a recover feature. I'll see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @MichaelT it works with [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/command_line.html) locally (`-metadata` option), but I don't think they have a cloud service yet (https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml-server/issues/21). I'll put my PlantUML diagrams on imgur from now on since I can get back the source. Thanks for the draw.io example.

Comment: @MichaelT the PlantUML guys already made a fix, e.g., http://plantuml.com/plantuml/?metadata=http://i.stack.imgur.com/HJvKF.png

Comment: Excellent.  It makes it a lot easier for people - both the long term usability of the post by posting it to imgur (there have been posts where the images are gone and they've become... not as useful) and at the same time providing the ability to go back and modify the image based on the embedded information.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, everything is both an abstraction and a detail. The abstractions allow you to focus on understanding and manipulating the concepts involved while knowledge of the details allow you to implement them. To a solution architect, the progrmming language is just a detail, to a coder optimising a sort algorithm, a datatype is just an abstraction. I always recommend at least an awareness of the details at the level below those required which will help you avoid making poor or expensive implementation choices but  equally, I recommend an awareness of the concepts at the level above those required to understand the context your solution is expected fits into.

Comment: this doesn't seem to offer anything substantial over points made and explained in prior 12 answers

Comment: Apart from being short and sweet, this answer makes clear the relationship between the abstract/detail level required and the level desired.